# Which bus does the RPi 3's micro SD slot use?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card

Is it USB, PCIe, or something else? I ask because I'm looking for a way to read/write the hidden boot1 and boot2 partitions on an eMMC chip, and it just doesn't work over USB.

Comment: I thought it was discrete GPIO.  Have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=220839

Comment: See also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/117394/33476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the bus supporting SD cards is called SD bus. There is a [spec](http://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/networking_communications/SD/SD.pdf) for it if you're interested. The SoC of RPi 3 implements two controllers for this bus: one is connected to the microSD slot, and the other one to the WiFi controller in SDIO mode.

The Linux driver for SD/MMC/SDIO devices is called `mmc`, and it does provide access to the hidden partitions. To use the SD slot, you will need to boot from something else than the SD card.